# NodeJS popup alert for POST method

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using ***Expressjs*** for my project. I  want to show a popup in if the ***post*** request is success. So I need a way to show a popup alert in the client side when server side says. It's seems not possible. Can any one help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to split that problem to 2 steps,

First, you have to response to the client with an appropriate answer fit to some  convention you have established, for example:

```
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  res.json('{ success: true }')
})
```

Then, in the client, you need to check that response object and then to create the popup according the given result.

Answer (score 0):

it has to be made on the client side, on the success callback of your POST. Example : https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/